# 'chkconfig umountnfs.sh on' does not create symlink

Tags: debian, chkconfig, lsb

on Debian, the init script `/etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh` has default stop in runlevel `0` and `6`.

```
# Default-Stop:      0 6
```

but there is no symlink in `/etc/rc0.d/` or `/etc/rc6.d/` on my system. I am trying to enable the script in these runlevels, but `chkconfig` does not create the symlink

```
chkconfig umountnfs.sh on
```

I could create the symlink manually, but I believe the `chkconfig` script does more than just symlink. I think it also calculates dependencies and modifies the `.depend.*` files

**How can I enable `umountnfs.sh` script on shutdown ?**

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the script has no runlevels specified in `Default-Start:`, but only in `Default-Stop:`. In such case, the symlink has to be created using the low level utility `insserv`:

```
insserv -r umountnfs.sh
```

if you use `-v` it will be verbose and tell you what links it is creating.